# Iterate to Create Array of Three combinations of array of three

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

given an array of three:

```
double unorderedArrayOfThree[3] = {6, 7, 4};
```

and wanting to populate an array with the three possible pairings of the numbers in the first and second position of a new array for example:

```
6,7,4
7,4,6
4,6,7
```

I'm having difficulty working out an ordinal progression in a for loop.  How would I easily traverse the first array to create the second?

```
int main() {
  double unorderedArrayOfThree[3] = {6, 7, 4};
  double newArray[3][3];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //? something clever here
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: so you want to create a 3x3 matrix of doubles?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int main() {
  double unorderedArray[3] = {6, 7, 4};
  double newArray[3][3];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newArray[0][i] = unorderedArray[i];
    newArray[1][i] = unorderedArray[(i + 1) % 3];
    newArray[2][i] = unorderedArray[(i + 2) % 3];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is this *clever* enough?